# Is there any way to open the google cloud shell from powershell in windows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'v installed the google cloud shell, and i want to know if is there any command to initialize it from windows powershell.

Comment: You do not install the Google Cloud Shell or initialize it. It is a container running in Google Cloud. You do have to start the container. You can connect to Cloud Shell using any SSH client. Execute this command to see the SSH IP and port number to connect on: `gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh --dry-run` I wrote a program that interface with Cloud Shell in Go. This could be easily ported to PowerShell. https://github.com/jhanley-com/google-cloud-shell-cli-go

Comment: This comment is not specifically about cloud shell, instead using gcloud commands with PowerShell in general. When I started with Cloud Tools for PowerShell, soon realized that it is not actively maintained and hence does not support new features of Google Cloud. The command `gcloud` does not produce response in PS compliant way. Alternatively, got to know that we can use `ConvertFrom-Json` feature of PS as follows: `gcloud whatever-command-options --format json | ConvertFrom-Json`.
Thanks to the blog - https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-the-google-cloud-sdk-with-powershell-dacbd3581208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: No by using Powershell but yes using normal CMD.

You can use command [gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/cloud-shell/ssh) to open a new session from Powershell to your cloud shell instance using SDK Shell (CMD).  Before running the command, be sure that you have installed [Cloud SDK for windows](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows) so you will be able to ssh to your Cloud Shell instance.

Regarding Powershell, unfortunatelly based on [Cloud Tools for PowerShell cmdlet reference](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-powershell/#/) accessing (ssh) the Cloud Shell using Powershell is not yet supported. You can create a Feature Request in [Google Cloud Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to request this feature to be added to Powershell.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me a lot! regards.